# Detecting DropDownList (Statement Issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, using

i trying to use DropDownList in code behind but i get an error - the visual studio dont recognized the dropdownlist.
[image]

I was trying to put the "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"  statment but nothing changed.

This is my current statment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing these two `namespaces` `using System.Web.UI;`
`using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` if you are using `ASP.NET` try this code hope it will help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public void loadSuppliers(DropDownList ddl)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace below

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

If this still does not work ,try rebuilding the project.
In Visual Studio , go to Build menu and select Rebuild option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one namespace

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```